# Comparing Two tables without knowing columns information

Tags: sql

If I have two tables A and B. I want to know if this table are same or not ?
i.e check does columns match ?
and does data match ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  (SELECT * FROM Table1
   MINUS 
   SELECT * FROM Table2)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT * FROM Table2
   MINUS
   SELECT * FROM Table1)
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Query USER_TAB_COLUMNS for each table

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, 
    FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE'
```

And you can compare it for matching columns .

(hawk's answer will do it in one step.)